Old horror movie with small man-eating creatures
I'm trying to find an old horror movie I watched as a child many years ago. I don't remember much of anything by way of plot, but I do recall one scene from the whole thing that has stuck with me all these years:

The scene I remember takes place inside a house, possibly in a hallway but that I'm not 100% sure of. 
I do know it's nighttime for the scene and there is one person, maybe two, lying on the floor while some form of creatures are eating them.
I think maybe there is also a child that sees this happen but I'm not 100% sure of that either. 
Also the people being eaten were covered in some kind of green, slime-like substance that was also on the floor around them as well.
As far as when the movie was released I would say anytime before 1995, and presumably it's an American film or English-speaking at any rate, but other than that I can't really say.


A kid, eating people and green slime are featured heavily in TerrorVision, but it's more silly than creepy. See if the trailer looks familiar.

Possibly Troll 2 from 1990. Goblin-like creatures, who happen to be vegetarian, turn people into plants. Then they eat them. This leads to a lot of green slime. And the family's small boy (Joshua, played by Michael Paul Stephenson, who was around 12 at that time) saves the day.
The movie was an Italian-American production, with an Italian crew and an English cast, so the official language is English.
Here's the trailer:



The infamous "They're eating her" scene, which may fit your description (seems to be inside a house, hallway-like structure):




I've seen Trolls 2 so I know it's not that, it's similar, yeah, but it doesn't have that specific scene that I recall. Thanks though!
